# How to overcome limitations of \url{}?

Tags: urls

One major limitation of the url package is that ["the argument must not contain unbalanced braces."](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/url/url.pdf).

However I have the problem that sometimes URLs I have to include in my document do not satisfy this rule like the following example:

```
http://example.org/abc?param=}
```

Because of the balanced braces rule you can not use:

`\url{http://example.org/abc?param=}}`

Neither can you escape the curly brace `\url{http://example.org/abc?param=\}}`.

How can this URL be used in an LaTeX document?

I need to have it clickable and I need the line-breaking behavior for long URLs.

Comment: Is that even a legal url?

Comment: `\url{http://example.org/abc?param=%7D}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}

\edef\URL{http://example.org/abc?param=\string}}
\expandafter\url\expandafter{\URL}

\end{document}
```

[image]